# best way to store tweets, feedback, post in database

Tags: php, mysql

I already checked previous thread but it does not answer my question.

I am getting user tweets or feedback. They might contains special characters or multiple spaces.

I tried with  `mysqli_real_escape_string($text);`  but then it was not storing the tweets into table.
Here is that code:

```
function lookup($tweetid, $connection, $userid){
   $tweets5 = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets/".$tweetid.".json?count=1");
   //var_dump($tweets5);
   $json = json_encode($tweets5);
   foreach($tweets5 as $item){
       $text = $item->text;
       //Other fields
       $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', '');
       $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($text);
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
           return;
       }

       $insertQuery1 = "INSERT INTO twitter_retweet(`username`,`userid`,`tweet_text`,`text_id`,`time`,`month`,`year`,`date`,`user_follower_count`,`rt_count`,`constant`,`in_reply_to`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$userid."','".$text."','".$text_id."','".$tweet_time."','".$month."','".$year."','".$tweet_dtm."','".$follower."','".$rt_count."','".$constant."','".$inreplyto."')";

       if (!mysqli_query($con,$insertQuery1)){
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
           //      echo "error";
       }
  }
```

What is the way so that it can handle any kind of text and store into table? I used `varchar` data type.

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_()` and `mysqli_*()` functions. You can't do that. Take a look at the [PHP manual for `mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) - you'll find there's a function there that will do what you want.

Comment: @MikeW:  it was just type. I tested code containing `mysqli`.

Comment: You should be using `json_decode()` where you currently have `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MikeW: it gives `json_encode()` correct result to me, I think changing it does not make any difference